# MQTTnet: Cannot send/receive CorrelationData

Tags: c#, correlation, mqttnet

We are using the [MQTTnet](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet) library in its lastes version to communicate. General communication is working. It's possible to subscribe and publish. The Payload and the Topic are received. But when publishing a message with CorrelationData set, in the received message only the payload and the topic exist. CorrelationData is Null.
We tested it with another application using some other C++ lib. This can send and receive Correlation data. So I assume that the MQTT broker is fine.

Is there anything to consider/configure to be able to use the CorrelationData?

Comment: You have to make sure, that you are using protocol version 5, otherwise it should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Jeanot's answer the version can be set in the MqttClientOptionsBuilder.
Ex:

```
using (var mqttClient = mqttFactory.CreateMqttClient())
{
    var mqttClientOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
        .WithTcpServer("localhost")
        .WithProtocolVersion(MQTTnet.Formatter.MqttProtocolVersion.V500)
        .Build();
        
    await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(mqttClientOptions, CancellationToken.None);
}
```